# How to access ServerWebExchange in AOP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-aop

I'm using Spring Webflux and implementing aspect. I'm doing something with method arguments of controller using aspect like below.

```java
@Before("execution(public * *.controllers.*.*(..))")
public void do(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
  Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
  for(Object arg : args) {
    if(arg instanceof ServerWebExchange) {
      //do something.
    }
  }
}
```

However, to use this aspect I have to declare 'ServerWebExchange' which I don't use explicitly in method signature like below.

```java
public Mono<String> method1(String param1, ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
  //do something
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to access ServerWebExchange from aspect directly, is there any way?

Comment: you probably can just `@Autowire` in the `ServerWebExchange` if your aop class is a spring bean of some sort

Comment: we can get arguments which are used in actual method signature.

Comment: Just in case you are wondering why you did not get any helpful answers yet, I think it is because your question is (a) unclear and (b) lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you would have taken a little time in order to edit and improve the question, I am sure it would have been answered by now.